# Serve content in email based on IP address

Tags: javascript, email, ip

I'm trying to serve specific content in an email based on the recipients IP address. For example I would like to display an advert if the IP address falls within a certain range. As a start I am trying only to render the IP address in the email using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userip;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("Your IP is :", userip);
</script>
```

This works when inserted in to a webpage but is not executed in an email.

Can a similar method be used to display/assess a recipients IP address in an email?

Comment: what exact you want describe more

Comment: I would like to be able display an image in an email if the IP address falls within a certain range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assume an email client executes Javascript (hopefully it *doesn't*) and you can't assume it'll load any external resources (hopefully it only does so after the user explicitly gives their consent). Your best bet is to simply embed an image from an external server, and have the server return a custom image based on the IP address. I.e. the server serving the image will return different images based on the request's IP; in the email itself you have a simple static URL.

This may still fail you in all sorts of ways, for example when viewing the email in a web client, where the server may fetch the image and scan it for viruses before displaying it on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to design a code snippet for a marketing team to use so it needs to be as simple as possible. Is there any coding language that is allowed to excute when an email opens, rather than having to be executed before sending?

Comment: Any sensible email client these days will not execute anything and possibly not even load any external assets. So: no. Emails are emails, they're not web pages.

Comment: OK thought as much! Cheers for your input.